# SSL Error in thread with simple post request in python

Tags: python, multithreading, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to do a simple post request, I'm using a list because I want to send all my post request at the same time using thread. Here is an example of an url :

```
            s = "https://emoncms.org/input/post.json?node="+str(test)+"&json={test_stack_overflow:0}&apikey="+str(apikey)
            list.append(threading.Thread(target=requests.post, args=([s, ])))
```

I was using this code maybe 3 months ago and it worked perfectly.
I wanted to get back on this project this week and I realized that I got some errors, this one particularly :

```
Exception in thread Thread-14:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 94, in post
  return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 49, in request
  return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 457, in request
  resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 569, in send
  r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 420, in send
  raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: <unprintable SSLError object>
```

I got an other error, ConnectionError but I think it's due to the network or because the website can't follow it's activity or is down. I leave you the traceback if you want :

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(101, 'Network is unreachable'))
```

This code is only a part of my project, the code is running every minutes and I don't know why but this issue (SSLError) comes only maybe 10 times a day. I got this script running on different Raspberry Pi and some have the same problem but not the same frequency, others don't have it at all.

Any ideas on what is going ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `verify=False` in the requests method like this

```
import requests
url="https://emoncms.org/input/post.json?node="+str(test)+"&json={test_stack_overflow:0}&apikey="+str(apikey)
requests.post(url,verify=False)
```

If you are using with threads then it will be like

```
list.append(threading.Thread(target=requests.post, args=(url,),kwargs={"verify":False})) #**kwargs should be passed seperately.
```

You are getting this error because python requests tries to verify certificate for https connections so you have to override it by passing `verify=False` or you can also provide certificate in verify like this `requests.get(url,verify="/path/to/certificate.ext")`

Also I doubt that this should be a get request because query parameters won't come in post request as of my knowledge. So if you use `GET` method same `verify` applies there too.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try this, I will tell you if it is working !

Comment: I got a SyntaxError, I'm trying to figure it out by myself but I'm just starting Python. Hope you will see the issue !

Comment: I think you might get error at verify=False I ven't tried verify=False under list of urls. Try with a single url you might get some idea.

Comment: Either `args=([url, verify=False,])` or `args=(url, verify=False)` is wrong, I still got SyntaxError ! `liste.append(threading.Thread(target=requests.post, args=(url, verify=False,)))`

Comment: If I passed kwargs like you said it works fine, I just got a warning `InsecureRequestWarning` but I think you can modifiy the traceback to avoid having a big one

Comment: Insure lRequestswarning is due to urllib3 used internally by python requests. Ignore it.

Comment: Yes I know more or less what is it and I know this isn't really important but it don't to have such a big message in my log just for a simple warning. I will check if I can modify it with just the message `InsecureRequestWarning`

Comment: use `import requests.packages.urllib3
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()` to disable warnings.

Comment: I went on some forums and I didn't realized that this solution was that unsafe